# lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 139; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'beans:bean'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

i want to register my custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter but when i do it i got an error that Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'beans:beans'.I know that i made a mistake somewhere in  tags but i don't know how exaclty this tag works. Here is spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">
 <bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
</bean>
<bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login" />
</bean>
<bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?error=true" />
</bean>
<bean id="myAuthFilter"
 class="com.webproject.MyAuthFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
</bean>

<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/courses**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/mycourses**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/courses/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                       users-by-username-query=
                "select username,passwort, enabled from users where username=?"
                                       authorities-by-username-query=
                "select username, user_role from user_roles where username =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. You have an element `<beans:beans id="..." ...>` in your configuration which is invalid. Maybe you meant `<beans:bean id="..." ...>` instead? If not, why do you think that element must have an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT :

Your default `namespace` is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security` so apart from security namespace all other namespaces you need to refer with `<beans:bean>`

So your following declaration is valid and correct.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema
```

Complete configuration should look like,

```
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">
 <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?error=true" />
</bean>
<beans:bean id="myAuthFilter"
 class="com.webproject.MyAuthFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/courses**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/mycourses**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/courses/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                       users-by-username-query=
                "select username,passwort, enabled from users where username=?"
                                       authorities-by-username-query=
                "select username, user_role from user_roles where username =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: i've done like you said and now it shows error that Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans:bean'. Also i've updated the code in question.

Comment: @Papich I have updated my question. Please use the config xml as posted. The global definitions is required but only defaults to first namespace always and in your case it is spring security so all spring security tags you can refer without <beans:bean>

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans:beans id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" ...
```

- this one should have been

```
<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the namespace `xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`, you are using the `beans` namespace for specifying beans, So your beans should be like

`<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login" />
</beans:bean>`

or

change your namespace of beans from 
`xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`  to `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`